# Sitecore.Ship with Sitecore 9

Tags: deployment

I am using Sitecore.Ship with Sitecore 9.0.1 to automate CI and CD build on Azure and also using TDS, I downloaded Sitecore.ship from Git, changed the .net framework to be 4.6.2 and built the solution.  However when i try to test Sitecore.Ship on my local machine using URL http://test/services/package/install

I got below error, any idea why and is there anther better way to automate the build

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (="...ï¿½%ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
>   ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½
>
> System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
>   collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +11943747
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection
>   collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +200
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +59
>   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.Package.InstallPackageCommand.GetRequest(HttpRequestBase
>   request)